# Can one connect an AF_INET socket to an AF_UNIX?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking

Can we connect AF_INET socket to an AF_UNIX? IS that possible? Please elaborate.

Comment: No you cannot, and there's nothing to elaborate about.

Comment: actually... can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Just want to know is that possible?

Comment: How could it be possible? What form of address would you use, given that they are different address families? The question doesn't begin to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AF_UNIX` is also known as `AF_LOCAL`, an address family whose (hopefully obvious, by the alternate name) use is for communications *on the same machine*.  `AF_INET`, by contrast, is the family of *Internet* addresses, which are probably not on your computer.

So, no.  They're incompatible addresses.  If the sockets do somehow connect on some platform, it's because the libraries decided you can't possibly be doing that.